# What should be used with a person or 3rd person , comparative degree or simple form of adjective

Tags: adjectives, singular, comparative-degree, third-person-singular

A person is becoming good day by day.
or
A person is becoming better day by day.
or 
A person is getting better day by day.
or 
A person is being good day by day.

Which one is correct and why?

Answer (score 2):

The most natural choice is "A person is getting better day by day." The phrases *getting better* and *day by day* both suggest an ongoing process, so they are compatible.

*Becoming better* is not a correct construction because *becoming* refers to a goal which the person is striving towards. *Better* is not a goal, it is a step towards a goal.

*Becoming good* is a correct construction, because good is the goal. And it describes an ongoing process, so it is compatible with *day by day*. So I think "A person is becoming good day by day" is also technically correct, although it sounds awkward.

A person who is *being good* has already reached the goal. This is not an ongoing process so it is not compatible with *day by day*. Instead you could use *every day* which does not imply an ongoing process : "A person is being good every day."